# Laravel5 eloquent relation from and lazy load

Tags: forms, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I've have relation in my model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');
}
```

And form:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['profile.update'], 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
 ...
<div class="form_block"><span class="form_label">First Name</span>{!! Form::text('profile[first_name]') !!}</div>
 ...
```

The problem is, that by default relation is fetched "lazy" way, so I need to manually call **$user->profile->first_name** for form value.
Or use something like this in controller:

```
 $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $user = User::with('profile')->find($user_id);
```

So maybe some eloquent have some option to control lazy load on relations?
Didn't found any information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for something Laravel calls [*Lazy Eager Loading*](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).

```
$userWithProfile = Auth::user()->load('profile');
```

Comment: I don't think that load() actually returns anything. You access the profile instead like this:

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->load('profile);
    $userWithProfile = $user->profile;